# filtrar array de objetos com base em array de string

Tags: javascript, json

Olá tenho um array de objetos assim:

```js
product: [
  { id: "1", name: "product 01" },
  { id: "2", name: "product 02" },
  { id: "3", name: "product 03" },
  { id: "4", name: "product 04" },
  { id: "5", name: "product 05" }

]

list: [ "1", "2", "5" ]
```

Gostaria de um resultado parecido com esse, aonde ele filtra apenas os objetos que estão registados na lista pelo Id:

```js
newArray: [
  { id: "1", name: "product 01" },
  { id: "2", name: "product 02" },
  { id: "5", name: "product 05" }

]
```

Acho que tem que usar o filter com o map, mas estou com dificuldade de fazer essa união

Comment: não entendi o resultado final por `list: ["1", "2"]` e no resultado tem 1, 2 e 5?

Comment: Foi editado há pouco tempo: "[4] Improve syntax highlighting" e incluiu esses valores à mais. Porém, acredito que para o resultado com ID: 5, deveria ser assim o `list: ['1', '2', '5']`.

Comment: Evitem colocar texto como foto pois dificulta a leitura em alguns dispositivos. Copiem e colem a saída.

Comment: realmente, me desculpe. O erro foi meu... vou concertar

Comment: Agora sim fez sentido!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use o [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

O [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) retorna `-1` caso o elemento que está buscando não exista no array. Então você pode usar em conjunto com o `filter()` para buscar um array de IDs em um array de objetos.

```js
product.filter(item => list.indexOf(item.id) !== -1)
// Output:
// [
//   { "id": "1", "name": "product 01" },
//   { "id": "2", "name": "product 02" }
// ]
```

#### [Ver screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlH08.png)

Comment: Por que eu teria que colocar o !== -1, pois quando fui testar no meu código o resultado trouxe apenas o ultimo producto, e quando coloquei o !== -1, trouxe o resultado correto. Pensei que ele era apenas caso não encontrasse o resultado e não interferiria tanto assim. Pq isso ocorre?

Comment: Olá, @SarahRodrigues. No caso, o `indexOf()` retorna a posição no array do elemento que você está procurando. Ou seja, se você está buscando os IDs `['1', '2']` num array de objetos `[{'id': '1'}, {'id': '2'}, {'id': '3'}]`, o `indexOf()` retornará respectivamente `0` e `1` para os IDs encontrados, e `-1` para o ID: 3 que você não está buscando.

O `!==` serve para comparar o valor e o tipo ao mesmo tempo, uma checagem de segurança. Mas no caso, se você não colocar `!== -1`, será considerado como verdade tudo que não for `0`. Acredito que retornaria os IDs 2 e 3, que estão errados.

Comment: Ahhh entendi!!! muito obrigada!!!

Answer (score 1):

Talvez esteja querendo isto:

Parametros para pesquisa:
[Array Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)
[Array Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains)

```
const products = [
   {id:1, name: 'product 1'},
   {id:2, name: 'product 2'},
   {id:3, name: 'product 3'}
];
const newProduct = products.filter((product) => product.id < 3)

console.log(products)   
console.log(newProduct)

idFilter = [1, 2]
const filterProduct = products.filter((product) => idFilter.includes(product.id))    

console.log(filterProduct)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Infelizmente não, tanto a lista de products quanto a list podem ter varios valores, vou mudar um pouco para vc entender.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, talvez te atenda agora, deixei o exemplo anterior, para que possa comparar o uso somente do filter e o uso do filter com incluedes.